# How to prove that $f$ is continuous on union of closed sets if it is continuous on closed sets

Tags: general-topology, continuity

The following question was left as an exercise in my class of topology and I am not able to make any progress on this.

> Question: Let $f:A\to B$ be a function where $A$ and $B$ are topological spaces. If $F_1$ and $F_2$ are closed in A and $F_1 \cup F_2 =A$, $f|_{F_1}$ and $f|_{F_2}$ are continuous,  then show that $f$ is continuous.

I am not sure what exact result should I use to prove it. Can you please sketch a proof of it?

Comment: Probably a reasonable thing would be to show that for any closed subset $C$ of the space $B$, the preimage $f^{-1}[B]$ is closed. (In the other words, using the characterization of continuity via closed sets.)

Comment: BTW you can probably find some similar questions on the site. After spending some time searching, I found: [Union of continuous functions on closed (or open) subsets is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3348987) and [$f$ is continuous if and only $f|X_1$ and $f|X_2 $ are continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2702188)

Comment: I think you can take a closed set $V\in B$ and show that $f^{-1}(V)$ is closed: It is the union of two(finitely many) closed sets $f^{-1}(V)|_{F_1}$ and $f^{-1}(V)|_{F_2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show $f$ is continuous is equivalent to $\forall C \subseteq B$ closed $ f^{-1}(C) \subseteq A$ closed. So let $C \subseteq B$ closed, then $f^{-1}(C)=f^{-1}(C \cap (F_1 \cup F_2))= f^{-1}((C\cap F_1) \cup (C \cap F_2)) = f^{-1}(C\cap F_1) \cup f^{-1}(C \cap F_2)$ $ = f^{-1}|_{F_1}(C) \cup f^{-1}|_{F_2}(C)$. Since $f^{-1}|_{F_1}$ and  $f^{-1}|_{F_2}$  are continuous and the finite union of closed sets is also closed $f^{-1}|_{F_1}(C) \cup f^{-1}|_{F_2}(C) = f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $A$. This shows $f$ is continuous.